# Detecting user position with Kinect without PSI pose

Tags: openi-tracker, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I searched the documentation and forum and did not find any answer to this question, but I might have missed something. So apologies if this is a solved issue.

I'm a very new to ROS so this might be a rather silly question. I would like to know if the openni_tracker node is able to post the user detection event and the rough user position before the PSI pose is calibrated.

I know the tracker prints that a new user is detected or gone to the terminal, but is there a topic with this information I could use?

Also, is it possible to track a user rough position before surrendering to the machine (assuming the PSI pose)?

Should I be using another node in order to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30575/detecting-user-position-with-kinect-without-psi-pose/) by [Carlitos](https://answers.ros.org/users/2062/carlitos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, the short answer is no, the openni_tracker node cannot publish the rough user position before calibration.

However, OpenNI offers a function called GetCoM (get center of mass) that gives you the rough position of the user without requiring calibration.

To use it, you should write your own node, or modify the openni_tracker code so that it uses that function to obtain the user position and publishes it either to /tf or to a specific topic of your choice.

You can create a copy of the openni_tracker code, as suggested by @McMurdo, and modify it so that it publishes the CoM before calibration and the full skeleton after calibration.

Don't hesitate to ask for help if you run into trouble.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2012-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1